# Idiomatic way to document Clojure defn's

Tags: documentation, clojure, standards

What is the idiomatic way to document function definitions (`defn`) in Clojure? In particular, should we use "`@param`", "`@returns`", etc. to document parameters, return values, etc.?

Is there some standard way to specify expected parameter types (other that type hints) in this dynamically typed language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a very strong tendency to use @param tags though I think they may be more common. the @returns tag it perhaps less applicable because it would make a lot of sense to put the entire description of what the function does under the @returns tag.

typically the code in clojure.core sticks to describing what the function does and a lot of them start with the word "return".

```
(defn rand-nth
  "Return a random element of the (sequential) collection. Will have
  the same performance characteristics as nth for the given
  collection."
```

There is a tendency in idomatic clojure code to try to use the build in sequence abstractions for most functions so rand-nth's doc string could look like:

```
(defn rand-nth
  "@Params: any seq
   @Returns a random element of the (sequential) collection. Will have
   the same performance characteristics as nth for the given
   collection."
```

which does not really say a lot more than the origional.

Comment: Ulfeld: I agree, but at least the `@param` lets you know what the argument `[x]` should be. I know there are conventions for naming arguments (`coll`, `idx`, etc.) but they don't seem to be followed consistently.

Comment: @Ralph: but _if you_ follow the convention consistently, you don't need `@param`.